# Restore pre-iOS7 UINavigationController pushViewController animation

Tags: objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, pushviewcontroller

So. Just started transitioning my IOS code to IOS7, and ran into a bit of problem.

I've got a `UINavigationController`, which has child ViewControllers and I'm using `pushViewController` to display the next views. To create a parallax animation with a set of images, if customized the `UINavigationController` to animate a set of `UIImageViews` and my child ViewControllers all have a `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`, transparency.

Since iOS7, the way the `UINavController` animates it child vc's, is updated, by partially moving the current view controller and on top pushing the new viewcontroller, my parallax animation looks crap. I see the previous VC move a bit and then disappear. Is there any way I can restore the previous `UINavigationController` pushViewController animation? I can't seem to find this in the code.

```
WelcomeLoginViewController* welcomeLoginViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeLogin"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:welcomeLoginViewController animated:YES];
```

Even tried using:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         [self.navigationController pushViewController:welcomeLoginViewController animated:NO];
                         [UIView setAnimationTransition:<specific_animation_form> forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                     }];
```

Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: For the record, the stock animation (i.e just the straight push with animated:YES) exhibits the same behavior now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys for the feedback. Found a solution in completely recreating the UINavigationController's behavior. When I was nearly finished I ran into Nick Lockwood's solution:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/OSNavigationController

OSNavigationController is a open source re-implementation of UINavigationController. It currently features only a subset of the functionality of UINavigationController, but the long-term aim is to replicate 100% of the features.

OSNavigationController is not really intended to be used as-is. The idea is that you can fork it and then easily customize its appearance and behaviour to suit any special requirements that your app may have. Customizing OSNavigationController is much simpler than trying to customize UINavigationController due to the fact that the code is open and you don't need to worry about private methods, undocumented behavior, or implementation changes between versions.

By overriding my UINavigationController with his code, I was able to work with background images in UINavigationcontrollers

Thanks!

Answer (score 46):

I managed to workaround the new transition type by creating a category for `UINavigationController`. In my case I needed to revert it to the old transition style because I have transparent viewControllers that slide over a static background.

- UINavigationController+Retro.h

  ```
  @interface UINavigationController (Retro)

  - (void)pushViewControllerRetro:(UIViewController *)viewController;
  - (void)popViewControllerRetro;

  @end
  ```
- UINavigationController+Retro.m

  ```
  #import "UINavigationController+Retro.h"

  @implementation UINavigationController (Retro)

  - (void)pushViewControllerRetro:(UIViewController *)viewController {
      CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
      transition.duration = 0.25;
      transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
      transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
      transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
      [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

      [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
  }

  - (void)popViewControllerRetro {
      CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
      transition.duration = 0.25;
      transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
      transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
      transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
      [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

      [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
  }

  @end
  ```

Comment: Hi Arne, Thanks for your solution. However you animate the UINavigationController's view instead of the child views of the controller. That way, the navigation bar exhibits different behavior. Tried solving by creating a completely custom animations of both views, but still not getting the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. However, when the user taps the Back button, it reverts to the busted animation (because the back button doesn't call popViewControllerRetro).

Comment: Bill, you can replace the back button with ```leftBarButtonItem```. 
I chose transition.duration = 0.4 because it seemed to be closer to the old speed, at least on the Xcode simulators.

Comment: This did the trick for me - I also had a viewcontroller with transparent background being pushed onto NavigationController with transparent background and a background image. The new iOS7 transition looked like crap, I'm wondering why Apple cannot just add those new features "silently", without "brute-enforcing" changes to native UI behaviour - gives us all a lot of trouble and headaches!

Comment: This worked wonderfully for me. I was using clearColor for my viewControllers (in order to get smooth animation underneath on UIWindow subviews), but got an annoying random stutter until implementing this.

Comment: Thanks for this great solution... I noticed one thing , when I call pushViewControllerRetro with time interval 0.4 I can see black color while transition. Any one saw this behavior ? Also simple popViewControler:animated works for me. So still do I need to use popViewControllerRetro ? Thanks

Comment: @iOSAppDev, I'm seeing the same thing! The black and white colours... anyone a fix?

Comment: @Martin I didn't get any solution yet

Comment: @iOSAppDev I think we should create a new question for that... After slowing it down to around 1 sec, I've found that it is because the old VC flashes white and the new one too. Check it out. By any chance, did you find some other solution?

Comment: @iOSAppDev - I found the solution. What I and probably you did, is add a background layer to the UINavigationController `[_navController.view insertSubview:_someSubview atIndex:0];` ... Now what I do is add the background view to the UIWindow as a subview instead... `[self.window addSubview:_someView];` and call `[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];` in every `viewDidAppear` of the UIViewController being pushed. Works fabulously! :)

Answer (score 22):

I have the same problem with clear background colors and crappy animations, so I create custom transitioning for ViewController with new iOS7 API. All you need is simply set a delegate for your navigation controller:

```
// NavigationController does not retain delegate, so you should hold it.
self.navigationController.delegate = self.navigationTransitioningDelegate;
```

Just add this files into your project: [MGNavigationTransitioningDelegate](https://gist.github.com/ArtFeel/7690431).

Comment: Very useful! Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution breaks autolayout - when you rotate and go back  the views are all broken on the previous page until you rotate again.

Comment: Good solution. I made Swift 3 version of your gist: https://gist.github.com/steryokhin/f136bd3e0c38b0fcdbff30b311714257

Comment: @Tom Maybe this would help https://gist.github.com/ArtFeel/7690431#gistcomment-1912196

Answer (score 18):

I had a problem where when UIViewController A did a pushViewController to push UIViewController B, the push animation would stop at about 25%, halt, and then slide B in the rest of the way.

This DID NOT happen on iOS 6, but as soon as I started using iOS 7 as the base SDK in XCode 5, this started happening.

The fix is that view controller B did not have a backgroundColor set on its root view (the root view is the one that is the value of viewController.view, that you typically set in loadView).  Setting a backgroundColor in that root view's initializer fixed the problem.

I managed to fix this as follows:

```
// CASE 1: The root view for a UIViewController subclass that had a halting animation

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame

{

     if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

          // Do some initialization ...

          // self.backgroundColor was NOT being set

          // and animation in pushViewController was slow and stopped at 25% and paused

     }

     return self;

}

// CASE 2: HERE IS THE FIX

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame

{

     if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

          // Do some initialization ...

          // Set self.backgroundColor for the fix!

          // and animation in pushViewController is no longer slow and and no longer stopped at 25% and paused

          self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // or some other non-clear color

     }

     return self;

}
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, but unfortunately my view B has clearColor, I've just have to add exactly the same image background as self.parentViewController.view.xxxxxx and now it works... thanks!

Comment: Yes, this exactly fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Crazy solution. Worked for me also !

Comment: How did you get that? i could have tried Voodoo instead..thanks

Answer (score 7):

First of, I'm not using Storyboard. I tried using UINavigationController+Retro. For some reason, the UINavigationController is having a hard time releasing the UIViewController at the top of the stack. Here's the solution that works for me using iOS 7 custom transition.

1. Set delegate to self.

   ```
   navigationController.delegate = self;
   ```
2. Declare this UINavigationControllerDelegate.

   ```
   - (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController (UINavigationController *)navigationController 
   animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
   fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC 
   toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC 
   {
       TransitionAnimator *animator = [TransitionAnimator new]; 
       animator.presenting = YES;
       return animator;
   }
   ```

   Note that it'll only get called when animated is set to YES. For example

   ```
   [navigationController pushViewController:currentViewController animated:YES];
   ```
3. Create the animator class extending NSObject. I called mine TransitionAnimator, which was modified from TeehanLax's TLTransitionAnimator inside [UIViewController-Transitions-Example](https://github.com/TeehanLax/UIViewController-Transitions-Example).

   TransitionAnimator.h

   ```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   @interface TransitionAnimator : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>
   @property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isPresenting) BOOL presenting;
   @end
   ```

   TransitionAnimator.m

   ```
   #import "TransitionAnimator.h"
   @implementation TransitionAnimator
   - (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
       return 0.5f;
   }
   - (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
       UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
       UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];    
       if (self.presenting) {
           //ANIMATE VC ENTERING FROM THE RIGHT SIDE OF THE SCREEN
           [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:fromVC.view];
           [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toVC.view];     
           toVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2*APP_W0, APP_H0); //SET ORIGINAL POSITION toVC OFF TO THE RIGHT                
           [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] 
               animations:^{
                   fromVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, (-1)*APP_W0, APP_W0, APP_H0); //MOVE fromVC OFF TO THE LEFT
                   toVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, APP_W0, APP_H0); //ANIMATE toVC IN TO OCCUPY THE SCREEN
               } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
               }];
       }else{
           //ANIMATE VC EXITING TO THE RIGHT SIDE OF THE SCREEN
       }
   }
   @end
   ```

   Use presenting flag to set the direction you want to animate or which ever condition you prefer. Here's the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to Apple reference.

Comment: Great. One thing is no need to use presenting variable. UINavigationControllerOperation indicates this operation is Push or Pop.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

This:

```
[[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

The final result:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in iOS7 there's a new way define your own custom UIViewController transitions. Look in the docs for UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate. Also, here's a link to an article about it: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/

Comment: Unless I am wrong, this seems to only work with presenting a view controller. I could not make it work when pushing a view controller to a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 implementation of Arne's answer:

```swift
extension UINavigationController {
  func pushViewControllerLegacyTransition(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.25
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
    transition.type = .push
    transition.subtype = .fromRight
    view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
  }

  func popViewControllerLegacyTransition() {
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.25
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
    transition.type = .push
    transition.subtype = .fromLeft
    view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    popViewController(animated: false)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another great resource to help out:

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

Using iOS7 TLTransitionAnimator to create custom animations

Answer (score 0):

I voted for @Arne's answer, because I find it the most elegant solution to this problem. I would just like to add some code in order to answer to @Bill's problem from his comment on @Arne's solution. Here's comment quote:

> Thanks, this works for me. However, when the user taps the Back
>   button, it reverts to the busted animation (because the back button
>   doesn't call popViewControllerRetro). – Bill Oct 3 at 12:36

In order to call popViewControllerRetro when back button is pressed, there's a small hack you can perform in order to achieve this. Go into your pushed view controller, import UIViewController+Retro.h and add this code in your viewWillDisappear method:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self] == NSNotFound) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerRetro];
    }

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

This if statement will detect when Back button is pressed and will call popViewControllerRetro from category class.

Best regards.