# iOS 7 UINavigationController transition style - View overlapping

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, transition

I 'm currently moving my application from iOS 6.1 to iOS 7 and I 'm just wondering if it is possible  somehow to keep the old style of UINavigationController transitions between views and not using the iOS 7 view overlapping. Is that possible?

I hope this [ios 7 view with transparent content overlaps previous view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881427/ios-7-view-with-transparent-content-overlaps-previous-view) not to be the only solution.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restore pre-iOS7 UINavigationController pushViewController animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867248/restore-pre-ios7-uinavigationcontroller-pushviewcontroller-animation)

Answer (score 0):

What actually I wanted to do is described in the following thread. Thanks!

[Restore pre-iOS7 UINavigationController pushViewController animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867248/restore-pre-ios7-uinavigationcontroller-pushviewcontroller-animation/18882232#18882232)